# row stays highlighted after mouseover

Tags: html, css

I've come across a strange artifact in Chrome (works fine in Safari):

[image: row highlighting artifact]

As you can see, the rows stay highlighted when scrolling up but not when scrolling down. I'd like the row to return to it's original background color.

Here's the basic table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="checkmark" rowspan=2>
      </td>
      <td rowspan=2>
        OrderCreate
      </td>
      <td>
        Elemica
      </td>
      <td>
        Mr. Widgets
      </td>
      <td>
        23 Jan 2013 13:04:35
      </td>
      <td>
        49384038503940394
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4>
        <span>DOC ID</span>
        <span>273ASHDF2347SDFH</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm doing a little bit of binding with KnockoutJS and Lift (Scala) but nothing crazy (and there are no issues anywhere else, or in Safari). So hmm.

And here's the CSS

```
tr {
  height: 38px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $bg-color;
  background: white;

  &:hover {
    background: darken(white, 10%);
  }
```

Any suggestions? I might look at another way to get this done as this path is a bit ... stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, we're all adults here (kinda). It's ok. You can give a reason why you downvoted. It's helpful.

Comment: What is the code you're using to generate the effect?

Comment: Right. Let me dig up the scss.. is that the downvote? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly on the css.. my bad. I'm looking in a dense codebase.. I was just wondering 'cause I'm all ears, improvement-wise.

Comment: So you want the cell with the rowspan=2 to remain highlighted on mouseover and mouseout?

Comment: No, I'd like the rows to only be highlighted on mouseover and return to white(ish) on blur (when the mouse leaves the element). I'll make that clearer.

Comment: It's a rendering error. Chrome is full of them. If we could have the speed of Chrome with the rendering stability of IE, then we'd have a perfect browser... maybe.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful and helpful comment @NiettheDarkAbsol. I'd heard as much asking around so I thought I'd turn to the SO community for the final word. Gratzie.